# Using PowerShell to get the Vnet name by resource ID in Azure

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-resource-manager

Assuming I have an Azure resource ID
Such as:

"/subscriptions/XXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/YYYYYY/providers/Microsoft.ZZZZ/WWWWW/my-resource-name"

How can I find out to which Vnets its connected/sits in using PowerShell commands?

Comment: please clarify what you mean by this "How can I find out to which Vnets its connected/sits in using PowerShell commands?". What kind of resources are you talking about? VMs?

Comment: Any type of resource that is connected to a certain vnet, for example also child resources

Comment: "connected to a vnet" is not a term that makes it clear, what you really mean

Comment: For example:
Virtual network gateway, Network interface, Load balancer, Scale set instance, VM. 
If I have the resource Id, I want to extract what is its Virtual network/subnet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be possible ,but you have to write lengthy code for it.(e.g If you have Network interface you need to use if block for it, so that it gets you the network interface `subnetid` and then again `elseif`for any other resource ).

**Azure portal provides a feature called connected device** from their we can simply check the devices are connected to the V-net.
As shown here:
[image]

Using Powershell CMD if you get the virtual network you can determine the associated resources in the subnet :-

[image]